# R - using rvest to scrape <p> tag only if a sister <img> tag is also present in nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping college basketball player images and `https://unfospreys.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster/2020-21` is one of the many pages with these images. Unfortunately, the 15th player on this page, Britney Gore, does not have a player image. As a result, the above data.frame() is not created because the column `imgSrc` is length 14 and the column `playerName` is length 15. (you can run the code separately for each column in the data.frame() and each line works individually).

[image]

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
rosters_url = 'https://unfospreys.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster/2020-21'
rosters_page = rosters_url %>% read_html()
    
this_rosters_df <- data.frame(
  baseUrl = 'https://unfospreys.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster/2020-21',
  imgSrc = rosters_page %>% html_nodes('div.sidearm-roster-player-image a img') %>% html_attr("data-src"),
  playerName = rosters_page %>% html_nodes('div.sidearm-roster-player-name p') %>% html_text() %>% trimws(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Is there anyway for the code to identify on this page - *okay, this player doesn't have an image tag, so don't pull their name, so we don't have this mismatch in the data frame?* I cannot change that there are only 14  tags to the 15

tags, but perhaps I can change the code for `playerName` to exclude all nodes that don't have a child/sister  tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solve this problem is retrieve the parent nodes for all of the players. Then parse this vector of parent nodes for the requested information for each player, using the `html_node()` function (notice no ending s).

This technique works for this problem since there is a one-to-one relationship between the player's parent node to the requested information.  For example one name, one position. The advantage of using `html_node()` instead of `html_nodes()` is `html_node()`will always return a value even if it is NA.  So when there is no image node a NA is returned and your vectors stay aligned.

```
library(rvest)

rosters_url <- "https://unfospreys.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster/2020-21"
rosters_page <- rosters_url %>% read_html()

#find the parent node which has all of the desired information for each player
players <- rosters_page %>% html_nodes(".sidearm-roster-player")

#Extract the requested information for each player
baseUrl = 'https://unfospreys.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster/2020-21'
imgSrc = players %>% html_node('img') %>% html_attr("data-src")
playername <- players %>% html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-name p') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

#build the final answer
data.frame(baseUrl, imgSrc, playername)
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepting this as it seems like the more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could grab a shared parent and thereby restrict to only those where both targets are present. I choose a selector for parent node that allows me to pull the name from an aria-label attribute (to match with displayed name after a substring replace)

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

rosters_url <- "https://unfospreys.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster/2020-21"
rosters_page <- rosters_url %>% read_html()
parent_nodes <- rosters_page %>% html_nodes(".sidearm-roster-player-image.column")

this_rosters_df <- map_df(parent_nodes, ~ {
  data.frame(
    imgSrc = .x %>% html_node(".lazyload") %>% html_attr("data-src") %>% url_absolute(., rosters_url),
    playerName = .x %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr('aria-label') %>% str_replace(' - View Full Bio',''),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
})

head(this_rosters_df)
```